# Create CSV file with post build event C#

Tags: c#, file, github, repo, post-build-event

I have some dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, string> myDict = new Dictionary<int, string>;
```

Dictionary holds:
1,mike
2,john
....

I want to create a CSV file from the dictionary with post build event but also ignore the file in repo.

I use the following to create the file:

```
String csv = String.Join(
    Environment.NewLine,
    data.Select(d => $"{d.Key};{d.Value};")
);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(pathToCsv, csv);
```

Can I do this with post build event or other way?
Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your demand ? What do you have in your dictionnary ? What do you mean by when .dll is built (by who?) ?

Comment: Dict holds some numbers and prople names for example.
When project is build at visual studio...

Answer (score 1):

I would look into [Roslyn source generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview). With this you would generate a file at compile time, so the generated file is not in your repository but available at run time